# ASP.NET C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on developing a solution for my website that will grab headlines and news articles from my database and display the 4 latest Headlines on my homepage with links to the full articles. I created a custom form that displays the information in a format that I would like. I tried creating a method in the code behind that would create one of these objects and populate itself with information from the database. This method would be invoked 4 times to display them in a vertical list. This is not going as smoothly as I thought it would. Does anybody have any ideas on how I could go about doing this. This code has to be dynamic since it will pull open a different article every time to display on the homepage. I'm new to the datagrids so if there is something that I can customize for this please point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: can you show us what you tried and what didn't worked

Answer (score 2):

Hey There,
I would do the following.

in the ASP.net Page

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <p><%# Eval("PostName") %></p>
    <p><%# String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ssss}",Eval("PostDate")) %></p>
    <a href="<%# Eval("PostAddress") %>">click here</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

and in the Code Behind.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<Post> posts;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        posts = new List<Post>();
        posts.Add(new Post { PostDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01"), PostName = "Post1", PostAddress = "www.post.com" });
        posts.Add(new Post { PostDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-02"), PostName = "Post2", PostAddress = "www.post.com" });
        posts.Add(new Post { PostDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-03"), PostName = "Post3", PostAddress = "www.post.com" });
        posts.Add(new Post { PostDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-04"), PostName = "Post4", PostAddress = "www.post.com" });
        posts.Add(new Post { PostDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-05"), PostName = "Post6", PostAddress = "www.post.com" });
        posts.Add(new Post { PostDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-06"), PostName = "Post7", PostAddress = "www.post.com" });

        // Load Posts into Control
        LoadxPosts(4);


    }

    private void LoadxPosts(int xPostNum)
    {

        var postxList = posts.OrderByDescending(x=> x.PostDate).Take(xPostNum);

        ListView1.DataSource = postxList;
        ListView1.DataBind();

    }
}




public class Post
{
    public string PostName { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public string PostAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these headlines are readonly in the form, you should consider a [repeater](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I would simply load the posts in the code behind ie:

```
public List<Post> posts;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    posts = new List<Post>();
    posts.Add(new Post { ID = 1, Value = "Post 1" });
    posts.Add(new Post { ID = 2, Value = "Post 2" });
}
```

Then iterate over the posts in the web form:

```
<%foreach( Post post in posts) { %>
<p><%= post.Value  %></p>
<% } %>
```

That avoids having to perform any nasty data binding.

Comment: nasty data binding? how about nasty code soup. if your going to do inline code looping/rendering - may as well use dynamic html - e.g a server-side placeholder and render HTML onto that. as least the code is in the code behind, not on the HTML. :)